How to prevent regular loss of heartbeat in spring kafka
There is a service built with Springboot(~3.0.1) which consumes events from a Kafka topic. This service regularly loses heartbeat and becomes non-functional.
The service does several writes to a MySQL tables based on incoming events. It uses a Redis cache to get the data that needs to be written to the tables.
Note : Auto commit has been disabled.
What has been observed so far:
Every 1.5 days, the time since last heartbeat increases linearly till the app stops consuming messages from Kafka (Number of active consumers for the topic becomes 0).
This behaviour is predominantly seen in production and not easily reproducible on dev machines or lower environments.
What has been tried:
Assuming that the root of the problem is time taken to process events increasing linearly and
based on various forums, Kafka documentation and other StackOverflow posts the following settings have been tweaked
session.timeout.ms to allow for longer time to process an event
max.poll.interval.ms to allow for longer time between subsequent polls
max.poll.records  to reduce the amount of time spent processing records fetched in a single poll
The number of consumers in a group have also been tweaked but the app continues to show loss of heartbeat.
Edit1: Updated version of springboot
Edit2: Added Info

Do you utilize spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout and other related Spring Boot auto-configuration properties? Do we really talk about loosing heartbeat from Kafka Client or your consumers are leaving the group because of too long processing time? Note: Spring Boot 2.7.x is out of Open Source support: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

@ArtemBilan, that config has not been tweaked, will look into it and get back to you. Losing heartbeat is what is observed first, then the consumer leaving group happens.

Right. So, looks like poll-timeout is too short to keep consumer in the group.

Hi @ArtemBilan, the poll-timeout config did not work. The same behaviour persists. It is also noticed that if the processing time per message can be brought down, the consumers.dont leave the group .

So, you might consider to use pause/resume on your containers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/pause-resume.html#page-title
